# Disable SignalR Backplane When Not Needed

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr

I am working on a SignalR application and I intend to make it scalable using Azure Message Bus and Azure autoscale. However, based on my expected user base, I anticipate that 90% of the time, my application will only have one instance running.

I would like to only have the backplane active if there are more than one instances, since the backplane architecture increases the travel time of a message and the message bus will cost me money. I definitely recognize that the travel time and costs are very small, but there's no reason to have them, if there's no reason to have them.

**Q: Is it possible to make the service bus backplane for SignalR dynamic so that it can be enabled and disabled based on need?**

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Probably, but this is uncharted territory and there's no telling what would break if you actually implemented a bus that dynamically scaled out on demand. Sounds like a cool experiment though...